# Как переслать файл из чата в другой, используя 2-х ботов?

Tags: python, бот, python-telegram-bot

У меня есть 2 бота: первый получает сообщение, которое может содержать файлы, фото, видео и т.д. Второй бот должен в точности отправлять все содержимое сообщение во второй чат.

```
@log_errors
def all_media(update: Update, context: CallbackContext, chat_id: int):
    file_id = update.message.document.file_id
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
    context.bot.send_document(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, document=file_id) #Вот это работает

    request = Request(
        connect_timeout=0.5,
        read_timeout=1.0,
    )
    bot = Bot(
        request=request,
        token=settings.TOKEN_BOT_2,
    )
    bot.send_document(chat_id=chat_id, document=file_id) #Вот это не работает
```

У каждого бота своя файловая система и наверное поэтому не получается переслать, как это сделать? Во второй беседе есть только второй бот, то есть просто переслать не получится

Библиотека: python-telegram-bot v13

Answer (score 0):

Таким образом вы никак не сможете это решить.
Во-первых, боты не могут взаимодействовать друг с другом.
Во-вторых, `file_id` - фото, видео и тд, по нему доступно только в пределах одного бота. Другой бот об этом `file_id` знать ничего не будет

Как вариант, физически сохранять документы на сервере, где один бот сохраняет, а второй бот забирает.

Можно сделать еще один чат, куда добавить уже оба бота, и оттуда забирать файлы

Comment: Я уже решила проблему без сохранения на сервере и общего чата, спасибо.

Comment: @Alone_Fox разрешили вопрос, то поделитесь своим решение. Мало ли, вдруг у кого-то еще возникнет подобный вопрос